# Calculated Value in Cell of Table Visualization

Tags: tableau-desktop

I am new to tableau, and am making a table with columns of 'Month'
and rows is a combo of 'Status' and 'Type'

my **data source** looks like this

| Month | Status | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 0 | Bird |
| Jan | 1 | Bird |
| Feb | 1 | Cat |
| Feb | 1 | Cat |
| Mar | 0 | Bird |
| Mar | 1 | Bird |
| Mar | 1 | Cat |
| Mar | 1 | Cat |

Let's say I want my table visualization to show a 'Percentage with status 1' for the month, and animal type (as below)

How do I do this in Tableau?

**(desired) visualisation**

|  | Jan | Feb | Mar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bird | 0.5 |  | 0.5 |
| Cat |  | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

For this case, I found a way to 'skin this cat'

See screenshot

[image]